# How do I programatically list my LinkedIn contacts?

Tags: java, linkedin-api

I have searched the LinkedIn APIs, but I cannot see a way to get the contacts. I know that there are some applications that have this functionality, but I am wondering is this legal or if they use some kind of partner API?

Comment: Have you tried this  :http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1004 ?

Comment: This seems ok for me. I don't know how did I miss it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the [Connections API](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api) probably does what you need.

This is a Web API, so from Java you would need to use an `URL.connect()` or Apache `HttpClient` or something like that, using an appropriately formed request URL.  Then you'd need to configure an XML parser to parse the XML response body and extract the contact details.

As the page states, your client needs to be authenticated (as you) to access your contacts, and the API won't let you see details that you cannot see using your web browser.

Comment: above link is not working right now. So could you correct it.

Comment: Fixed.  (For the record, Google can find it easily ...)

Comment: tnks, can you suggest, how to retrieve first connection's ids to get his/her profile like email, company info, picture (ideally same as profile of the current user, but in above link only name comes).

Comment: It says that you can only get full details for >>your<<  1st degree connections.

Answer (score 0):

I created a plugin for Play Framework to easily integrated with LinkedIn's OAuth: http://geeks.aretotally.in/projects/play-framework-linkedin-module.

Hopefully it can help. You should def check out Play, very very cool Java framework.

Comment: @Ajay2707 you can find it here https://github.com/feliperazeek/playframework-linkedin

Answer (score 0):

1) First click below link and add your app to developer account

The ***r_network*** scope recently changed to be a LinkedIn partner-only permission. You can apply for access to their partnership program here: 
https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

2) After successfully creation of your app on developer account make permission of ***r_network***

3) Insert Following code after importing all required linked-in sdk file from this https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk

```
private static final String topCardUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,email-address,last-name,num-connections,headline,picture-url,industry,summary,specialties,positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,type,size,industry,ticker)),educations:(id,school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities,notes),associations,interests,num-recommenders,date-of-birth,publications:(id,title,publisher:(name),authors:(id,name),date,url,summary),patents:(id,title,summary,number,status:(id,name),office:(name),inventors:(id,name),date,url),languages:(id,language:(name),proficiency:(level,name)),skills:(id,skill:(name)),certifications:(id,name,authority:(name),number,start-date,end-date),courses:(id,name,number),recommendations-received:(id,recommendation-type,recommendation-text,recommender),honors-awards,three-current-positions,three-past-positions,volunteer)?format=json";



       public void getUserData() {
            APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
            apiHelper.getRequest(MainActivity.this, topCardUrl, new ApiListener() {
                @Override
                public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse result) {
                    try {

                       //here you get data in json format
                       //you have to parse it and bind with adapter for connection list

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onApiError(LIApiError error) {

                }
            });
        }
```